# Is it possible to switch from dark mode to light mode after installing breeze in dark mode?

Tags: laravel-breeze

I am using Laravel v10.6.2 (PHP v8.1.0). I installed [`breeze`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze) in dark mode now I want to be able to switch to light mode.
Is it possible to change the dark theme of the code generated by breeze?
(**Note**: without reinstalling Breeze.)

Answer (score 3):

In file tailwind.config.js

Add

```
module.exports = {
  darkMode: 'class',
  // ...
}
```

More info [in tailwind documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode#toggling-dark-mode-manually)

Comment: didn't work! it just ruined the whole css! testing laravel breeze v10.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me without reinstalling breeze. In your tailwind.config.js file, inside export default, add this:

```
darkMode: 'class'
```

Uncomment this if you want to switch back to dark mode

Answer (score -1):

Yes of course you can. When you install laravel breeze with dark mode, it didnt installed it only in "dark mode". It just added support to be able to adapt the view accordingly, and it is default to follow your system mode. When you change your computer to light mode, breeze ui will update to view the light mode. You can change this by changing in tailwind.config.js, like mentioned, by changing 'darkMode' to 'class'.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to disable dark mode completely just reinstall with

```
php artisan breeze:install
```

This reruns the install procedure and you can now avoid to install dark mode.

Be aware this will overwrite some files related to Breeze.

Comment: My question says without reinstalling Breeze, thanks.

Comment: Reinstalling worked for me.